# Nesting with three levels of quotations

Tags: php, double-quotes, quote

I am trying to create a php variable that has three levels of nested quotes. How do I make a third level around `"tackEvent"`, `"downloads"`, `"all"`, and `"nofilter"`? The double quotes that I have there are not working.

```
  $outputList .= "<a href=files/".$content_file ." onClick='_gaq.push
(["_trackEvent", "downloads", "all", "nofilter"]);' >" . $content_name . 
"</a>";
```

Comment: can you please give us more detail on this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From [here](http://blog.opensourceopportunities.com/2007/10/nested-nested-quotes.html):

- Outer quote = " (This marks the beginning and end of the string)
- Inner quote = \" (Escaped as to not flag "beginning/end of string")
- Third-tier quote = ' (Literal quote)
- Fourth-tier quote = \' (Literal quote that will be generated as an
  escaped outer quote)

Comment: Sometimes is more convenient to use `'` at second level, so only need to start escaping at third level. That is, switch "inner" and "third-tier".

Answer (score 3):

- Outer quote: `"`
- Inner quote:  `'`
- Third-tier quote:  `\"`
- Fourth-tier quote:  `&quot;`

Comment: Fourth quote is & q u o t ;

Comment: This does not answer the question. _why_ do you believe this is the answer? _how_ does it work? Simply telling someone to change their code without any context or meaning does not help them learn what they did wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
$outputList .= <<<LINK
<a href="files/$content_file" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'downloads', 'all', 'nofilter']);">$content_name</a>
LINK;
```

This is using [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (\). To
>   specify a literal backslash, double it (\\).

This applies to strings in double quotes as well.

```
$str = "I am a string with a quote that says, \"I like quotes\"";
```